# DDE - Windows cannot find path

Tags: winapi, dde

I have problem with handling DDE if I want to show `CDialog` before creating `CFrameWnd`. I do it in two ways:

1) create `MyApp` (`CWinApp`) which has overriden `OnDDECommand`. Inside `MyApp::InitInstance()` I create `MainFrame` (`CFrameWnd`). DDE works well, `OnDDECommand` handles DDE calls.

2) before `MainFrame` I want to show `MyDialog` (`CDialog`), but in such situation I don't get `OnDDECommand`. I tried to handle `WM_DDE_EXECUTE` (and other `WM_DDE_` messages) inside `MyDialog`, but such messages don't come.

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep your `CFrameWnd` hidden at startup.
2. Let the `CFrameWnd` process the DDE message.
3. During processing open the dialog.